# How to set default value and if not then the value from AsyncStorage in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am new to React Native, so trying to learn.
I am trying to set the default value using hooks in react native as below

```js
const [recent, setRecent] = useState('No data')
```

I am using the async storage to get the value of recent. If the value is not found in async storage then I need to set the default value as `No Data`

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `useEffect` hook. It will run when the component is first mounted. In it you need to run an async function to check AsyncStorage for the value. That has to be done in a specific way, which I've shown in the example below (create async function, then immediately run it). Then update the value based on what it finds.

```
const [ recent,setRecent ] = React.useState()

React.useEffect(() => {
    const checkAsync = async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
        if (value !== undefined && value !== null){
            setRecent(value)
        } else {
            setRecent('No data')
        }
    }
    checkAsync()
}, [])
```